# Have table cell grow horizontally when cell content is large

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table within a wrapper div that is set to scroll on overflow (i.e., `overflow: auto;`).

This works nicely when placed in a container div that has a fixed width. If my table (which is being built server side) happens to have a lot of columns and gets too wide, gets a scroll bar placed at the bottom, making it semi-mobile friendly.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <!-- more html here... -->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, when I have a cell which contains a lot of text, the cell will typically grow in height to fit the content.

Since I'm using a scrolling overflow, I'd like for the cell to tend to grow more in width, which would give it a better visual appeal.

Here are some examples:

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Manual fix for cell with lots of text */
.manual-fix {
  width: 400px;
}

/* minor display stuff */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

table tr th {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Table within a wrapper so it overflows nicely and you can scroll.
</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
          <td>lorem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>

<h1>
Table still within a wrapper yet coincidentally fits without the need for a scrolling overflow.
</h1>

<h2>
This is only because it has a small number of columns.
</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>
Table that still overflows, but wraps long text poorly.
</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>

<h1>
Table with a "manual fix" in place what I'd like to automatically happen when a cell has a lot of text in it.
</h1>
<h2>
Essentially, I'd like for a cell to have a max height, and increase its width when it reaches that max height so the content doesn't overflow.
</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ipsum</td>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
          <td><div class="manual-fix">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>dolorcing</td>
          <td>sit</td>
          <td>amet</td>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

At the bottom example, I've manually expanded the width of a cell with large amounts of text to show what I'd like to happen (without the manual fix, of course).

**Essentially**, what I'm looking for is when a cell has a lot of text, for that cell to have a maximum height, and for the cell to expand horizontally (rather than vertically) to fit the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the cell contents inside a non-tabular container with

```css
width: max-content;     /* Attempt to have maximum width required by content */
max-width: 400px;       /* without exceeding 400px */
min-width: min-content; /* unless the content really requires it (optional) */
```

In the future, it will be possible to write this as

```css
width: fit-content(400px);
```

Note not all browsers support `max-content` or `min-content`, and others need vendor prefixes.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Manual fix for cell with lots of text */
.manual-fix {
  width: 400px;
}

/* minor display stuff */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

table tr th {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

td > div {
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: -webkit-min-content;
  min-width: -moz-min-content;
  min-width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Table within a wrapper so it overflows nicely and you can scroll.
</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><div>1</div></th>
          <th><div>2</div></th>
          <th><div>3</div></th>
          <th><div><div>4</div></th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div>lorem</div></td>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
          <td><div>amet</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
          <td><div>amet</div></td>
          <td><div>lorem</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
          <td><div>amet</div></td>
          <td><div>lorem</div></td>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
  Table still within a wrapper yet coincidentally fits without the need for a scrolling overflow.
</h1>

<h2>
  This is only because it has a small number of columns.
</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><div>1</div></th>
          <th><div>2</div></th>
          <th><div>3</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div>lorem</div></td>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
          <td><div>amet</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>
  Table that still overflows, and wraps long text nicely.
</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><div>1</div></th>
          <th><div>2</div></th>
          <th><div>3</div></th>
          <th><div>4</div></th>
          <th><div>5</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div>lorem</div></td>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
          <td><div>amet</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
          <td><div>amet</div></td>
          <td><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div>dolorcing</div></td>
          <td><div>sit</div></td>
          <td><div>amet</div></td>
          <td><div>lorem</div></td>
          <td><div>ipsum</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never knew about `max-content`. Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I can make the determination if it is worth it to implement even though browser support is rather low ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width)). Here is a working fiddle using `max-content` https://jsfiddle.net/romellem/vbcmgbx3/5/

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` to `.container` class

Please find the working example here. [Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/NrqpXJ)

Comment: I want my `.wrapper` to have a scroll bar though. At the end of the day, my table is living in a grid system ([Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html) actually) which has a fixed width. If that table is too large, it should be scrollable.

Comment: You can have the overflow in wrapper and it would still work with position:relative; in container class

Answer (score 0):

Cell column won't grow wider on fixed width table. Give wrapper a lot of space for table to grow. Then with javascript (I use jQuery), adjust wrapper width to fit table's width.

**CSS**

```
.container {
   width: 350px;
   overflow:auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 10000px;
}

table { 
}
table td:nth-child(5) {
  max-width:400px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').width($(this).outerWidth());
  })
})
```

Here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeafgilbert/vbcmgbx3/4/).

Comment: I'd rather not use JS if possible, but the approach makes sense. Table displays at full width, then resize my wrapper after the content has been rendered.

However, you mentioned my "fixed width table." The table doesn't have a fixed width. It has `width: 100%` set.

Comment: 100% of its parent, which is wrapper's width, it is 100% of container's width, which is 350px.

Comment: But the table does grow to more than `350px`. If it didn't, I'd never see the horizontal scroll bar. I get what you're saying, but I think there is more to it still. Thanks for the help so far though, I'm wondering if I'll need a JS solution, or perhaps flexbox.

Comment: It forced to grow to fit all contents in. When it finds space, text goes down.