# Fixed height table with overflow-x for the cell content

Tags: css

I want my table cells to have a fixed height of 62px, I tried many solutions but I couldn't achieve this, and the one below is the closest one.

The problem I have is that the text inside my table cell is not displayed correctly, it's partially hidden.

The content of the table cells is dynamic, and my desired behavior, is for the table cell to grow in width to fit its content, and then the table will have a horizontal scroll since the overall width of the table would surpass its wrapper.

I know that `white-space: nowrap;` would solve the text overflowing issue, but I want the text to go to the second line because there is enough space for it `line-height of 24px * 2 < 62px < line-height of 24px * 3`. So it will either have one line or two lines depending on the cell min-width, and it the width of the cell will grow to fit it's content without having more than two lines, since three lines will result in a height > 62px

As for this solution:

[Have table cell grow horizontally when cell content is large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617809/have-table-cell-grow-horizontally-when-cell-content-is-large)

I can't use it, since the `min-content` property is not supported by IE11.

How can I solve this?

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: scroll:
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

tr>th:first-of-type,
tr>td:first-of-type {
  min-width: 70px;
}

table thead th {
  border-top-color: #d9deea;
  border-bottom-color: #6b7790;
  border-style: solid none solid none;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6b7790;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  min-width: 124px;
}

tbody td {
  color: #01216c;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 62px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #d9deea;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 124px;
}

td>span {
  max-height: 62px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: why don't You use overflow:hidden in your <td>'s

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez could you please check the example again, I've added `overflow:hidden`?instead of the text overflowing it gets hidden

Comment: I can't undesrtand your question anymore... you want a fixed height... which you have already... but want to see all the content?

Comment: Agree with @AlvaroMenéndez. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez, yes I want a fixed height, and the whole cell content to be visible not overflowed or hidden

Comment: then just reduce the font-size and line-height untill you can see it all... but it won't work if your content is dinamic.

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates  you cannot have a fixed height and expect long pieces of text will not be hidden.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez that's the problem I have the content is dynamic, if it wasn't I could of just used a min-width for my table cells, what I don't understand why the content gets hidden? why it doesn't just get fit.

Comment: @disinfor normally the table cell should grow in width so the text can get fit, but why it doesn't ?

Comment: Does your span height have to be a fixed 62 pixels in max height? If so, then you have an implementation problem. If you have control over the content on the span then reduce the "number of words" manually (not code change), otherwise you need to have your span expand dynamically to the total character count by removing the max height

Comment: @AGE yes it has a fixed height, but the table can have a horizontal scroll (`overflow-x: auto;`) so what I want is for the table cells to grow in width to display it's whole content, and then the table would have a horizontal scroll

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have table cell grow horizontally when cell content is large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617809/have-table-cell-grow-horizontally-when-cell-content-is-large)

Comment: @disinfor unfortunately it doesn't `min-content` is not supported by IE11

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates Then you need to add to your question that you need to support IE11.

Comment: IE11 supports (a bastardized version of) CSS grid... this would be way easier without tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible with pure css. But you can solve it with a small javascript. Increase the width of each table cell span until the height is small enough.

**Working example:**

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('td span');

for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  const td_style = window.getComputedStyle(spans[i].parentNode);
  const span_style = window.getComputedStyle(spans[i]);
  const line_height = parseInt(td_style.getPropertyValue('line-height'));

  while (parseInt(span_style.getPropertyValue('height')) > line_height * 2) {
    spans[i].style.width = (parseInt(span_style.getPropertyValue('width')) + 5) + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  min-width: 100%;
}

tr>th:first-of-type,
tr>td:first-of-type {
  min-width: 70px;
}

table thead th {
  border-top-color: #d9deea;
  border-bottom-color: #6b7790;
  border-style: solid none solid none;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6b7790;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  min-width: 124px;
}

tbody td {
  color: #01216c;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #d9deea;
  border-style: none none solid none;
}

td>span {
  display: block;
  max-height: 62px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

If you are using jQuery in your page you could simplify the script to:

```
$('td span').each(function() {
  const line_height = parseInt($(this).parent().css('line-height'));
  
  while ($(this).height() > line_height * 2) {
    $(this).css('width', '+=5');
  }
});
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('td span').each(function() {
  const line_height = parseInt($(this).parent().css('line-height'));
  
  while ($(this).height() > line_height * 2) {
    $(this).css('width', '+=5');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  min-width: 100%;
}

tr>th:first-of-type,
tr>td:first-of-type {
  min-width: 70px;
}

table thead th {
  border-top-color: #d9deea;
  border-bottom-color: #6b7790;
  border-style: solid none solid none;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6b7790;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  min-width: 124px;
}

tbody td {
  color: #01216c;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #d9deea;
  border-style: none none solid none;
}

td>span {
  display: block;
  max-height: 62px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer after reading in your question that the whole table should have the horizontal scroll and not every table cell

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates i changed the jQuery script to plain javascript and simplified the function. Please give a feedback...

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses a `min-width` on the third and fourth `td` elements.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table thead th {
  border-top-color: #d9deea;
  border-bottom-color: #6b7790;
  border-style: solid none solid none;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6b7790;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
}


tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1),
tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
  min-width: 100px;
}

tbody tr td:nth-of-type(3),
tbody tr td:nth-of-type(4) {
  min-width: 300px;
}

tbody td {
  color: #01216c;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 62px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #d9deea;
  border-style: none none solid none;
}

td>span {
  max-height: 62px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what if the content is too long in a row, and in another row is too short, this solution requires you to not have dynamic content.

Comment: @RenaudisNotBillGates, yeah, I know this won't necessarily work with dynamic content. Is the content in the first two columns relatively the same length? You show longer content in the third and fourth columns, but not the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the table container width.

Your table container has a fixed width of 600px which forces the divs to stretch as best they can. Increasing this or giving each  a specific width would help to fit your content more.

Comment: Thanks, but I did that on purpose because the table will have an horizontal scroll if the content doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Another practical, elegant and easy to implement solution is using `overflow-y: auto;` on table cells. Here are a couple of reasons why you should consider this instead of your current desired behavior:

1. Resizing tables or table elements horizontally is suboptimal UX. Table based designs should only be used to display tabluar data by definition, and should generally have a fixed horizontal size and variable vertical size.
2. Does not require any JS black magic in order to solve an otherwise basic problem of sometimes showing the user more text.
3. We can also adjust the `line-height` to 20px for tds, this way we can comfortably see 3 text rows without showing a scroll bar. Bonus: some browsers such as Safari have actually nice looking scroll bars.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

tr > th:first-of-type, tr > td:first-of-type {
  min-width: 70px;
}

table thead th {
  border-top-color: #d9deea;
  border-bottom-color: #6b7790;
  border-style: solid none solid none;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6b7790;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  min-width: 124px;
}

tbody td {
  color: #01216c;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 62px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #d9deea;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 124px;
}

td > span {
  max-height: 62px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have made 2 changes -

1. add property `overflow-y:auto` to add vertical Scrollbar on fixed height cell for td>span
2. change `line-height: 1rem` in `tbody td` properties or you change as per your requirement. Vertical space will be removed and less Y-Axis scroll required

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: scroll:
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

tr>th:first-of-type,
tr>td:first-of-type {
  min-width: 70px;
}

table thead th {
  border-top-color: #d9deea;
  border-bottom-color: #6b7790;
  border-style: solid none solid none;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 24px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6b7790;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  min-width: 124px;
}

tbody td {
  color: #01216c;
  line-height: 1rem;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 62px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #d9deea;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 124px;
}

td>span {
  max-height: 62px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, minus?</span></td>
        <td><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo beatae quidem, molestiae sequi iusto amet voluptas maiores. Accusamus, dicta culpa?</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```